# Deeplink with specific language

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I am facing with a specific problem with deep link. 
I mean , for the universal Link I have something like

```
https://www.website.com/LANGUAGE/dashboard/profile
```

that means language can be `/en/ /fr/ /de/ /it/ /es/` and more...

The problem is I try in my Manifest :

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
         android:host="www.website.com"
         android:scheme="https"
         android:path="/*/dashboard/profile"/>

</intent-filter>
```

But the `*` does not work. Any solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, its possible by doing something like this :

```
<data
     android:host="www.website.com"
     android:scheme="https"
     android:path="/.*dashboard/profile"/>
```

it will work for all language

```
https://www.website.com/en/dashboard/profile
https://www.website.com/fr/dashboard/profile
https://www.website.com/de/dashboard/profile
https://www.website.com/it/dashboard/profile
https://www.website.com/es/dashboard/profile
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Android doesn't support multi-language functionality for deep links. Therefore, you need to have a unique URL path for each language like:

```
<data
         android:host="www.website.com"
         android:scheme="https"
         android:path="/en/dashboard/profile"/>
```

Comment: @LikseN yes, or either the website should give you one deep link for all languages where the language will be taken from the system.